# Will this warning creates an issue further?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using java8 and I installed eclipse neon recently. When I run eclipse, I get this warning

**OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0**

Answer (score 0):

This error may occur many cases

**1.** if you didn't installed java then it will show error

**2.** if your system is 64bit and eclipse is 64bit and you have installed java only for 32 bit, then it will show error. for this you need to use java 64 bit or need to use eclipse 32bit.

**3.** if you didn't set java environment variable , then eclipse will not get java path, then it will show error.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a warning message it will not cause any issue.
If you wish you can remove the `MaxPermSize` from your eclipse.ini file and restart the eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

You get this warning because you are running Java 8 and in Java 8, the way Java manages memory has changed. (If you want to know the technical details, the memory area known as "permgen" was removed in Java 8; see [Where Has the Java PermGen Gone?](https://www.infoq.com/articles/Java-PERMGEN-Removed)).

The option "MaxPermSize" doesn't exist anymore in Java 8, and if it is specified anyway, then Java ignores it.

This usually doesn't do any harm, so you can safely ignore it.